# How create one query?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

One author has many books. There are many authors with books in the database.
It is required to get the latest books of authors. In one query.

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    author = models.ForegnKey("Autors", models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# its a many queries
last_books = []
for author in Autor.objects.all():
    last_book = Book.object.filter(autor=autor).latest("created_at")
    last_books.append(last_book)
# need one query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the answer in one query. Group the books by author and get the latest created_date of each group. Filter the records matching the created date in `latest_dates`

```
qs = Book.objects.all()
latest_dates = qs.values('author').annotate(latest_created_at=Max('created_at'))
qs = qs.filter(created_at__in=latest_dates.values('latest_created_at')).order_by('-created_at')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [**`Subquery`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

books = Book.objects.filter(author=OuterRef('pk'))
authors = Author.objects.annotate(book=Subquery(books.order_by('-created').values('name')[:1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Get all books by the author, sort in descending order and fetch first record

```
latest_books = []
for author in Author.objects.all():
    last_book = Books.objects.filter(author=author).order_by("-created_at")[0]
    latest_books.append(last_book)
```